# Generate list of first 100 prime number?

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers

I know how to generate a list of prime numbers up to a limit, but how would I generate the first 100 prime numbers in a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Table[Prime[n], {n, 100}]
```

This is in the documentation.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about the Prime function. Thank you!

Comment: `Prime[Range[100]]` works also.

Comment: @J.M. your approach will be a bit quicker too.

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo This is exactly what i was looking for. How would you sum up the first n primes given a number n as input?